# mysql insert not inserting the intended value

Tags: mysql

Am trying to write a simple MySQL insert query but i dont know why its inserting a wrong value

Here is my query 
INSERT INTO tp_shipping_to_parent_event(
                        shippingID, event_parentID, eventID)
                VALUES
                        ('265','5111601651','17523')

[Screenshot for the result after inserting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcgRr.png)
Row ID 15 is the newly inserted and '2147483647' under event_parentID is not '5111601651'. can someone assist and make me understand ?

Comment: 2 147 483 647 is the 32-bit integer limit, perhaps that's a issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the values i was trying to store are larger than the integer data type set for the field in db. The 2147483647 is the max integer value that can be stored. So i changed the data type for the field (to long values) and all is well now.